# Qt/CMake: missing ':' before identifier 'slots'`

Tags: c++, windows, qt, cmake, qmake

I am trying to compile the audio recorder example from Qt using my own cmake file instead of the qmake .pro file that comes with it, and I am receiving the following error:

`qtaudiorecorder\audiorecorder.h(63) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ':' before identifier 'slots'`

My CMakeFile:

```
find_package(Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS multimedia widgets)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Multimedia REQUIRED)
add_definitions(-DQT_NO_KEYWORDS)

add_executable(audio_recorder audiorecorder.cpp main.cpp qaudiolevel.cpp qaudiolevel.h audiorecorder.h audiorecorder.ui audiorecorder_small.ui)
qt5_use_modules(audio_recorder Widgets Multimedia)
```

audiorecorder.h:

```
#ifndef AUDIORECORDER_H
#define AUDIORECORDER_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QMediaRecorder>
#include <QUrl>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class AudioRecorder; }
class QAudioRecorder;
class QAudioProbe;
class QAudioBuffer;
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class AudioRecorder : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    AudioRecorder(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~AudioRecorder();

public slots:
    void processBuffer(const QAudioBuffer&);

private slots:
    void setOutputLocation();
    void togglePause();
    void toggleRecord();

    void updateState(QMediaRecorder::State);
    void updateProgress(qint64 pos);
    void displayErrorMessage();

private:
    Ui::AudioRecorder *ui;

    QAudioRecorder *audioRecorder;
    QAudioProbe *probe;
    bool outputLocationSet;

};

#endif // AUDIORECORDER_H
```

I can't figure why I can't compile the Qt example with my cmake file (it compiles fine with qmake).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is most likely the inclusion of

```
add_definitions(-DQT_NO_KEYWORDS)
```

in your cmake file.

Comment: Indeed, when defining `-DQT_NO_KEYWORDS`, one must use `Q_SLOTS` instead of `slots`, `Q_SIGNALS` instead of `signals`.

Answer (score 0):

In Qt "slot" is a special macro. In the normal process, the MOC(meta object compiler) will be invoked first to explain "slot" into some codes that can be understood by c++ compilers. I think there are some codes in .pro files that invoke MOC before giving files to c++ compiler.

All in all, you have to invoke MOC first, otherwise C++ compiler will complaint on "slot".

Comment: MOC is used to generate extra source files. It's effect on programmer-made source is zero. This sounds like somewhere in your program the macro `slots` has been `undef`fed somewhere, or your source is being processed before the Qt headers have defined the macro.

Comment: the keyword `slots` does nothing in c++ code, so it does not effect the compiler. `signals` on the other hand is like `protected` but will also add special implementations in the mocing process. the bigger question might be 'why use CMake instead of qmake?'

Comment: I thought that Qt5's `CMAKE_AUTOMOC` automatically does it for you for cmake. This is not a qt project. I just need to use some of its library. That library will be replaced later on down the road. We want to have working functionality to demonstrate first. Thanks for the comments and the answer.